# Etc/GMT+(offset) only providing GMT in PHP

Tags: php

According to PHP, the timezone in the format `Etc/GMT+(offset)` is a [valid timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php). Based on that, I would have assumes that this code would output a series of different timezomes:

```
$start_date = 'Dec 16, 2011';
$start_time = '09:45:00';
#$utime_zone = 'GMT'; <-- switching to GMT works!
$utime_zone = 'Etc/GMT';

for($i = -12; $i <= 12; $i++){
   $curr = ($i >= 0)?'+'.$i: $i;
   $str = ($start_date . " " . $start_time . " " . $utime_zone.$curr);
   echo $str . ' = ' . strtotime($str).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Unfortunately, the strtotime calls are all ignoring the timezone completely.

The output:
`Dec 16, 2011 09:45:00 Etc/GMT-12 = 1324028700`
`Dec 16, 2011 09:45:00 Etc/GMT-11 = 1324028700`
`Dec 16, 2011 09:45:00 Etc/GMT-10 = 1324028700`
`...you get the idea.`

Clearly I have made some assumption about this, but is there an easy way to convert from `Etc/GMT+(offset)` to a GMT timestamp?

Comment: There is a big warning on the manual page: Warning

Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.

Comment: @mkilmanas Unfortunately this was not in my control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why is your case not working (apart form the big PHP warning saying not to use that method), but you could easily work around it using [ISO-8601 date formatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

The format is basically `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` and then either `Z` for UTC or `+/-hh:mm`.

```
$datetime = '2011-06-20T18:49:00';
echo $datetime.'+01:00 => '.strtotime($datetime.'+01:00')."<br />";
echo $datetime.'+03:00 => '.strtotime($datetime.'+03:00')."<br />";
```

gives you

```
2011-06-20T18:49:00+01:00 => 1308592140
2011-06-20T18:49:00+03:00 => 1308584940
```