# How to set time zone in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone-offset

I have a site that has list of stores in different countries ( different time zones ), and it should display when store is OPEN or CLOSED by working hours.

I have javascript that gets DEFAULT timezone GMT offset when daylight saving isn't set, put it inside mysql, and that part works correctly.

My timezone is GMT+1 ( and now it's daylight saving active, so it's +1 hour now )

I use php to change zone using this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+1');
echo date('h');
```

Time here: 10 PM

GMT time: 8 PM

And this code return: 7 PM

So it's like it instead increasing by 1, it decrease, and plus there is no daylight saving...

Can someone tell me what happen here?
Is it php bug or something wrong on server?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently chuckling because I recently had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428135/etc-gmtoffset-only-providing-gmt-in-php). Unfortunately Etc/GMT timezones are deprecated. They break. My personal recommendation? Just use HH:MM or set it by the city (cities don't require daylight savings time adjustments!)

Comment: I can't get city, only GMT offset... And I can't use global time and increase/decrease it by offset because it won't be correct because sometimes daylight saving are set on my server, and on stores places isn't, or otherwise...

Comment: Etc/GMT is global time +/- an offset. If your server's savings time is not correctly set, you should be able to fix that my setting it to a city timezone. It will compensate for GMT appropriately in that case.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it has +/- reversed... But still there is no daylight saving...
Can I add for each GMT+X town that will match that time zone and apply daylight savings by that? Will that be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps date('I') might help in this situation.
Unless there is an option to define a look-up list [GMT offset] - [time zone name]. Then it will be possible to adjust time zone using DateTime\DateTimeZone classes.

Comment: date('I') will show is it in daylight saving period or not... And it's 0, like time hour is, otherwise there will be +1 counted...